# Disable Compatibility Mode in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, compatibility

Is there a way I can disable Compatibility View in IE8? It jumps into it every now and then, which results in rendering pages really oddly. Can it be turned off so it doesn't do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quite easily:

Internet Options> Advanced> Browsing> Uncheck "Automatically recover from
page layout errors with Compatibility View".

Comment: go to tools > compatibility view settings and remove all the websites in the list as well.